# Cannot run create-react-native-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, create-react-native-app

I'm trying to get started with react native, so I followed the "get started guide". I installed **create-react-native-app** without a problem, but when I try to create a project, here is what I get :

> npm ERR! Unexpected token ▼ in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '▼      >♥??
>   Mo?6►???...'

I'm using :

> node version : 6.11.4 
>  npm version : 5.5.1

Also I'm working behind a proxy, but I configure npm to work, for instance I could run `create-react-app` .

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are using npm version v5+ which according to official react-native documentation buggy and not supported. If you want to use npm only then use the 4.6.1 version.
Additionally you could use Yarn to use this command

Refer:
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app